# Kubernetes pods are going into crashloop backoff :Saying permission denied on starting the container

Tags: unix, kubernetes, dockerfile

I'm getting a case of `CrashLoopBackoff` while my logs say:

> "/abc.sh" permission denied.

This is my `DockerFile`:

```
FROM python:3.6.3

COPY abc.sh /abc.sh

CMD["/bin/bash","-c","/abc.sh"]
```

The entry point is given in deployment.yml file. After I apply the deployment.yml with the image created by above `DockerFile`, it shows:

> /abc.sh permission denied.

Despite the fact that permissions are 755 on `/abc.sh` and `/abc.sh` is having owners as `root:root`.

I have already tried:

```
FROM python:3.6.3

COPY abc.sh /abc.sh

USER root

CMD["/bin/bash","-c","/abc.sh"]
```

and

```
FROM python:3.6.3

COPY abc.sh /abc.sh

USER root

CMD ["su","-","root","/bin/bash"]

CMD["/bin/bash","-c","/abc.sh"]
```

I want to start the pod with 2 scripts:
1)one is entry point which is in deployment file 
2)other is in Dockerfile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use root for this case. This is happening because your shell script is not permitted to execute or an executable. You need to run the following before you run the shell script:

```
chmod +x /abc.sh
```

Comment: I just added this on my dockerfile , it works thanks.

Comment: :I am also trying to create a directory using docker file.RUN mkdir -p is not working.

Comment: @Nancy what are you running, and what error message are you getting?

Comment: No Error though: Running this
FROM python:3.6.3
MKDIR -p /opt/abc/log
COPY abc.sh /abc.sh

CMD["/bin/bash","-c","/abc.sh"]

Comment: Are you getting CrashLoopBackoff or are you simply not seeing the directory? @Nancy

Comment: Not seeing the directory when i do a plain docker run

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile? Either here or in a new question? @Nancy

Comment: I have another sort of query , so maybe a new question.maybe extension to  this question.

Comment: Will post the next questions link here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55462679/not-able-to-execute-efg-py-script-inside-the-container-as-arg-to-kubernetes-de

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191047/discussion-between-nancy-and-cookiedough).