# Not able to execute efg.py script inside the container as 'arg' to kubernetes deployment file

Tags: python-3.x, docker, unix, kubernetes

1) Trying to run `efg.py` script inside the container as an arg in the kubernetes deployment file.
2) Inside the container the file is present in `/opt/abc/efg.py`.

3) While running the deployment it is showing no such file or directory.
4) These are the container spec:

```
    spec: containers: 
       -name: abc
        image: <full path here to the registry and image>
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
        - name: PYTHONPATH
          value: "/opt"
        args:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - cd /opt/abc && python3.6 efg.py
```

logs:

> python3.6 :cant open the file : efg.py [errorno] no such file or directory exists.

The location of `efg.py` in the container is `/opt/abc/efg.py`.

Requirements:
1) Need to run the `efg.py`.
2) `egf.py` requires a log directory and a file to be created inside `/opt/abc/`. Something like this `/opt/abc/log/efg.log`.

a) either add mkdir in `Dockerfile` ("which is not working")
  b) add it in the args

Comment: Problem resolved.

Comment: Hello @Nancy Could you add your solution as an answer and mark it as approved? It will make your solution more visible if anyone will be searching for similar issues.

Comment: Solution: 1)Make the directory during docker image build
2)For running a script , give entry point in docker build or give it inside the deployment file in container specs as
        `command: ["/bin/bash"] `
       `args: [ "-c", "cd /opt/ && python3.6 efg.py" ]`

Comment: If you need a env variable to be exported inside the pod you can give it inside the deployment file.there are other ways , but this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Posting @Nancy comments as community wiki answer to be more visible.

Solution:

**1)** Make the directory during docker image build

**2)** For running a script , give entry point in docker build or give it inside the deployment file in container specs as command:

```
["/bin/bash"] args: [ "-c", "cd /opt/ && python3.6 efg.py" ]
```

In addition, if you need a env variable to be exported inside the pod you can give it inside the deployment file. There are other ways, but this worked for OP.